# How do I reset Virtual Box window to native resolution of guest OS with Ubuntu 12.04 as host?

Tags: virtualbox

How do I reset Virtual Box window to native resolution of OS?

I have stretched out my guest windows size and there is no menu to adjust it back to normal size.

Comment: Unfortunately your question isn't very clear. Please consider editing it to make it more understandable.

Comment: That better? I thought it was pretty clear. I am thinking the person who will answer this question will understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it was in [Scale Mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/59105/11929).

<kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is the toggle for scale mode (where <kbd>Host</kbd> is <kbd>Right Control</kbd> by default)